# Python Convert string to HTML char equivalent

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, html-encode, character-entities

Let's say we have a string

`Bruce Wayne is Batman`

When I convert this string to HTML characters, the output will be

`&#66;&#114;&#117;&#99;&#101;&#32;&#87;&#97;&#121;&#110;&#101;&#32;&#105;&#115;&#32;&#66;&#97;&#116;&#109;&#97;&#110;`

I am trying to find a way to do this in python 2.7. Can anybody suggest how it can be done?

I have searched all over the stackoverflow and all the answers I have found are how to escape HTML special characters. I am not looking to escape special characters, rather convert any and all the strings into their HTML char equivalent. The hackbar addon of mozila firefox is able to do it successfully, I want to implement the same using python.

Also the HTMLParse library is able to decode it successfully using the unescape() module. Is there a library in python to encode it the way it's mentioned above? Also I am not looking for external libraries like BeautifulSoup, rather an inbuilt library, as it will add no dependencies to the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there's nothing in the standard library to do this (encoding *every* character as its entity reference is not a common thing to need to do), but a function to do the conversion is straightforward:

```
def entitify(text):
    return ''.join('&#%d;' % ord(c) for c in text)
```

```
>>> entitify('Bruce Wayne is Batman')
'&#66;&#114;&#117;&#99;&#101;&#32;&#87;&#97;&#121;&#110;&#101;&#32;&#105;&#115;&#32;&#66;&#97;&#116;&#109;&#97;&#110;'
```

```
>>> entitify(u'Rinôçérôse')
'&#82;&#105;&#110;&#244;&#231;&#233;&#114;&#244;&#115;&#101;'
```

The function simply uses the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) builtin to get the byte value or code point of each character, wraps it in the `&#...;`, then joins the results together.

Comment: Does the job. Thanks.